# Why isn't my collection.update() working on my Server side, but working via the console?

Tags: javascript, meteor, mongodb-query

When i run the below `collection.update` code via the Chromium console, it executes flawlessly, however when it's executed on the server side, nu collection update actually happens.

I would appreciate any help explaining why this works client side but not server side.

**../server/main.js**

```
console.log("Unique_ID: "+unique_id+ " ...and STATUS is: "+paymentStatus );
```

In the terminal I get to see the print out of the above code:

**Unique_ID: SX43WLwHbKptpbJyN ...and STATUS is: Successful**

```
recipientsDetails.update({_id: unique_id}, {$set: { paymentStatus: paymentStatus } }, function(error, affectedDocs) {
      if (error) {
          throw new Meteor.Error(500, error.message);
      } else {
          return "Update Successful";
      }
  });
```

After this code runs (on Server side), "Successful" isn't set for row with _id: SX43WLwHbKptpbJyN.

Can someone kindly explain why this works when run via the console but NOT on the server side?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Including where the collection is defined, where the variables in your example are defined, how the code is executed and the folder structure of the files involved?